# Algorithm slowness for Project Euler #20

Tags: performance, lua

Here is the problem I am trying to solve: http://projecteuler.net/problem=20 (find the sum of the digits in 100!)

I am using Lua, which only has double as a number type, so I had to approach this manually. I am using almost the same code as I was using for problem 16, which was similar (find the sum of the digits in 2^1000). However, this time the problem seems to be beyond my algorithm to solve in a decent amount of time - it reaches about 32! before I have to wait longer than 10 seconds for it to calculate the next total, and by 34! it takes longer than I have waited. Is there any way I can speed this up (using 'raw' Lua - not LuaJIT or anything like that)?

```
local sum = {1}
for i=1,100 do
    local carry = 0
    for v=1,#sum do
        local c = carry
        carry = 0
        local t = sum[v] * i
        while t >= 10 do
            t = t - 10
            carry = carry + 1
        end
        local s = t + c
        while s >= 10 do
            s = s - 10
            carry = carry + 1
        end
        sum[v] = s
    end
    if carry > 0 then
        sum[#sum+1] = carry
    end
    print(""..i.."! = "..getCharactersReversed(sum))
end
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726586/project-euler-prob-20-lua

Comment: @Dr_Asik: I have searched! The answer says "What you need to do is implement your own algorithms for dealing with large numbers.", which is what have posted here that I need help with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the length of the decimal representation of `(n+1)!` can be more than one longer than that of `n!`. That first happens for `n == 14`,

```
14! =   87178291200
15! = 1307674368000
```

thus here your final `carry` is 13 and the leading "digit" is larger than 10. From then on, that problem becomes worse and worse, printing out `#sum` and the final carries yields

```
15      11      13
16      12      20
17      13      35
18      14      64
19      15      121
20      16      243
21      17      510
22      18      1124
23      19      2585
24      20      6204
25      21      15511
26      22      40329
27      23      108888
28      24      304888
29      25      884176
30      26      2652528
31      27      8222838
32      28      26313083
```

and reducing `leading_number * i` to a number smaller than 10 by stepwise subtraction takes increasingly long. At some point (estimated about 45), the value becomes so large that `t - 10 == t` and you're stuck in an infinite loop. LuaJIT wouldn't help with that at all.

So you have to make sure that you never write a digit larger than 9, for example by reducing the final carry in a loop like the previous digits and adding as many digits as needed. Doing that, the programme runs without noticeable delay.

```
if carry > 0 then
    local w = #sum+1
    local cc = 0
    while carry > 0 do
        while carry >= 10 do
            carry = carry - 10
            cc = cc + 1
        end
        sum[w] = carry
        w = w+1
        carry = cc
        cc = 0
    end
end
```

But determining the digit and the carry by division is much more concise, and for the larger factors also much more efficient (when multiplying a digit by 100, the result is on average 450, requiring 45 subtractions, but two divisions are sufficient for all factors).

Answer (score 0):

Try this short code:

```
    def factorial(n):
        return reduce(lambda x,y: x*y,[_ for _ in range(1,n+1)])

    print sum(map(int,list(str(factorial(100)))))
```